# When the UIAlertView appear,what view changes made to the viewcontroller

Tags: uiview, uialertcontroller

I want to know how the `UIAlertController` work. I am trying to develop loading a view which will do the same like `UIActivityIndicatorView`. When my loading view is appearing on the screen, I want to do the same thing like `UIAlertController` which code made the whole screen black and user interaction disabled to that view until the user click "OK". Any help please?

Comment: I guess you are trying to ask to create a custom `AlertView`? are you...???

Comment: No i just want to know which code made the view black and user interaction enable to false when the alert view appear.

Comment: That code is in `UIAlertView's` Class which is provided by iOS itself.

Comment: if you want to make it custom, you can add a UIView on whole screen with setting its alpha to some 0.5 or like this in black color.

Comment: You can also help me here,if u dont mind.I am having some problem with calling my custom alert from another view controller.Here is my link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30837238/how-to-call-my-custom-alert-controller-function-to-display-in-other-view-control