# How to call my custom alert controller function to display in other view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have write my custom alert view controller.But,I am having error at calling my alert controller from other view controller.It show me the error that I described below.

Error on console

```
2015-06-15 10:21:50.610 automobile[4197:62165] Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7d11cf70> on <automobile.LoadingAlertViewController: 0x7bfa55d0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Here is my `LoadingAlertViewController`

```
import UIKit

class LoadingAlertViewController: UIAlertController {

var loadingAlertController : UIAlertController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func displayLoadingAlert() -> UIAlertController {

    var controllerToPresent = viewController
    if controllerToPresent == nil {
            controllerToPresent = self
    }
    //create an alert controller
    loadingAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Loading...", message: "We are receiving data from network.Please Wait.", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    indicator.color = UIColor.redColor()
    indicator.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    loadingAlertController.view.addSubview(indicator)

    let views = ["pending" : loadingAlertController.view, "indicator" : indicator]
    var constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[indicator]-(7)-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
    constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[indicator]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
    loadingAlertController.view.addConstraints(constraints)

    indicator.userInteractionEnabled = false
    indicator.startAnimating()

    controllerToPresent!.presentViewController(loadingAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    return loadingAlertController
}

func dismissLoadingAlert() -> UIAlertController {
    loadingAlertController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    return loadingAlertController
}

}
```

Then I decalare this `LoadingAlertViewController` at my another view controller where i want to display every time that i request to my API.

This is my `ViewController`.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController : UIViewControler{

var loadingAlertController : LoadingAlertController!
var api = MyAPI()

override func viewDidLoad() {

       loadingAlertController = LoadingAlertViewController()

       api.getResults()

       showAlert(true)

}

func showAlert(alert : Bool){

       if alert{

          loadingAlertController.displayLoadingAlert(self)

       }else{

          loadingAlertController.dismissLoadingAlert()

       }

}
```

Any Help?Please?If there is a way,how to call it from another view controller.Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your method like so:

```
func displayLoadingAlert(viewController: UIViewController?) -> UIAlertController {
    var controllerToPresent = viewController
    if controllerToPresent == nil {
    controllerToPresent = self
}

// Most of your code

controllerToPresent.presentViewController(loadingAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

return loadingAlertController
}
```

Then when you're calling the alert:

```
loadingAlertController.displayLoadingAlert(self)
```

Alternatively:
Rename the method displayLoadingAlert to loadingAlert

Remove the line:

```
self.presentViewController(loadingAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

then when calling insidethe showAlert() method

```
let loadingAlertController = loadingAlertController.loadingAlert()
self.presentViewController(loadingAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: It work.I also updated the answer too.But,i don't quite understand the words that you said "then when calling insidethe showAlert() method...."

Comment: Your method showAlert(alert: Bool) method inside your second block of code.

Comment: Ohh I see.But,I think I dont need to do that now.I edited your answer which work perfectly for me now.Thanks for your help,@David Wong.

Comment: ,u can help me also on this one too.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30840235/console-warning-in-my-custom-alert-controller-which-said-it-was-attempt-to-prese

Answer (score 2):

I see you made as subclass, but in the [UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/) documentation is written:

> The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not
>   support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and
>   must not be modified.

I would recommend you do not go against it. If you need something very custom better to use UIViewController and display with custom behavior.